# Improving speed on du command on mount point

Tags: shell, unix, diskspace, du

Is there a way to improve speed on `du` command on mount point?

I am looking to retrieve occupied space of top level directory of a specified directory in bytes with below command on a mount point & I see its super slow.

```
du -b --max-depth=1 <mountName>
```

Whereas `df` on other hand works super fast to retrieve data of mount point.

Would like to know if there is a way to use `du` on mount point & get required data in a faster way?

Also is there a way to get sub-directory size ( in **bytes** ) on top level directory using *different* command on a mount point?

Comment: Related: [(U&L) How to cache or otherwise speed up `du` summaries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8485/273492)

Answer (score 4):

`du` traverses the directory tree, while `df` doesn't. That is why `df` is so much faster, but also only works on whole partitions -- it just reads that partition's metadata. I don't think there is a way around `du` being slower.

> Also is there a way to get sub-directory size ( in bytes ) on top level directory using different command on a mount point?

```
du -b -s <mountpoint>/*
```

Comment: Thanks @DevSolar for the pointer, but with `--max-depth=1` its already restricting to top level directories. I am exploring more on using _different_ or _alternative_ command which works bit faster to get result on which my cron job is dependent for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently copying several TB from one disk to another.
The cp command is running in a screen obviously.

Now, I did not know how to get an idea of the copying progress. du -sh was taking forever, similar to what you are describing. Actually it was so long my SSH session failed everytime because of wifi issues.

So, I ran the du -sh in a screen as well, redirecting the output to a file. I have no idea why, but this fixes the problem, maybe it is caching something. The screen running du exits very fast and after that I can run du -sh and get the result immediatly.